# How to handle Hibernate Exception?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I'm using Spring and Hibernate framework and trying to update an object that does NOT exist in DB (non existent entry) but it returns the error `HTTP Status 500`

```
HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateOptimisticLockingFailureException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1; nested exception is org.hibernate.StaleStateException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1
```

This is my service but it does NOT catch the exception

```
    @Override
    public ResponseEntity<?> update(CoverSheet coverSheet) {
        try {
            this.coverSheetDao.edit(coverSheet);                
            return CryptoUtils.generateSuccessResponseEntity(coverSheet);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();                
            return CryptoUtils.generateFailureResponseEntity(ErrorCode.CODE_SQL_EXCEPTION, e.getMessage());
        } 
    }
```

Could you pls help me? Many thanks!

Comment: It deppends on  the exception. You your case i would say there is an update for an non existent entry in the database, so i would send a 404 return code. But it only my opinion, without enough knowledge about your functionality

Comment: @Jens Could you please give me more detail?

Comment: Just to understand the question. Do you know where the exception is exactly thrown? If it is inside the try-block but is not caught then it is very surprising for me. It could be than there is something broken in the build process and it runs an outdated version of the code. The exception type should be caught by the catch(Exception) block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this error. The actual update query is executed at flush time. Not when calling update() on the session. In this particular case, the flush happens just before the transaction wrapping the call to the service method is committed. BTW, that can be seen in the stack trace:

```
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:485)
```

So I catch the exception outside of the service (Ex: Controller):

```
try {
        return contactService.update(contact);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return CryptoUtils.generateFailureResponseEntity(ErrorCode.CODE_SQL_EXCEPTION, e.getMessage());
    }
```